# Android frame animaton being forced stop. Need reason for it

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I have a ImageView -

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageAnimation"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

And a XML file, **animation_list.xml** for frame animation in the Drawable folder -

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/path1" android:duration="210" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/path2" android:duration="210" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/path3" android:duration="210" />

</animation-list>
```

I have the Java code for animation inside onCreate -

```
ImageView imageAnimation = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageAnimation);

imageAnimation.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation_list);

AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)imageAnimation.getBackground();


frameAnimation.start();
```

It is getting forced stop. What might be the reason for this ?

On debugging, this line -

```
imageAnimation.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation_list);
```

shows the error, **thread exiting with uncaught exception**  and **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget**

Comment: What do you mean by "forced stop"? Post you logcat please.

Comment: @Gissipi_453 which version of android are you testing it on?

Answer (score 1):

OK
you can not start the animation in `onCreate()`

try overriding `onWindowFocusChanged`, as follows:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
     super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
     frameAnimation.start();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @sajad for your time. The problem was that the images that I have for animation are too big in size, greater that 5MB each. Reduced image size, it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView imageAnimation = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageAnimation);

    imageAnimation.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.animation_list));

    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)imageAnimation.getBackground();

    frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imageAnimation.getBackground();

    frameAnimation.start();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @Hades for your time. The problem was that the images that I have for animation are too big in size, greater that 5MB each. Reduced image size, it works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the images that I have for animation are too big in size, each greater than 5MB. Reduced image size, it works.